Excel Formula Incorrect, not returning NA for result
Here's my formula
=IF(AND(XLOOKUP(A2,'PUMPKIN Inputs'!A:A,'PUMPKIN Inputs'!K:K)=""),"",IF(XLOOKUP(A2,'PUMPKIN Inputs'!A:A,'pumpkin Inputs'!K:K)<>"",CONCAT("Contract expires as of: ",TEXT(XLOOKUP(A2,'pumpkin Inputs'!A:A,'pumpkin Inputs'!K:K),"m/dd/yyyy")),"N/A"))

IN my spreadsheet the formula works on my date for this column returns the correct date, however i need it to return NA, for the column should NA be the correct answer instead of the date.  Pumpkin is just the name of the spreadsheet hope this helps

you will never get to the N/A because you already capture where it equals "" and put "" with the first IF.  Just use the second IF only.

Why not utilize the 4th argument of XLOOKUP: =TEXT(XLOOKUP(A2,'PUMPKIN Inputs'!A:A,'PUMPKIN Inputs'!K:K,"N/A"),"m/dd/yyyy")?

Also instead of repeating the same formula again and again , it is suggestive to use LET()

The last "NA" is never reached in your current formula.
your current formula
IF AND(XLOOKUP....) equals "" // true if "" else false
THEN ""
ELSE 
  IF XLOOKUP... is not equal to "" //This is always true
  THEN CONCAT(....)
  ELSE "NA" //Is never reached

You can simplify your formula to
IF (XLOOKUP(A2,'PUMPKIN Inputs'!A:A,'pumpkin Inputs'!K:K)<>"" , 
  CONCAT("Contract expires as of: ",TEXT(XLOOKUP(A2,'pumpkin Inputs'!A:A,'pumpkin Inputs'!K:K),"m/dd/yyyy")),
  "NA"))

